# Another tag for the bonfire: [good-design]

Tags: discussion, tags

Can [good-design](/questions/tagged/good-design) be anything but a synonym for Not Constructive?

Comment: I'd say either the code works, in which case it's a candidate for codereview.se, or it doesn't (or there is no code yet), in which case it's subjective/not a good question.

Comment: Might also be a migration candidate for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).